# Pan Panel for ol3

Tags: openlayers, pan

I've created an ol3 map for a web application. Now, I am trying to create a Pan Panel for this map. I've disabled the dragPan and touchPan (because of external circumstances) and now I want a clickable Pan Bar/Panel like in OpenLayers 2 maps (example: http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/pan-zoom-panels.html). Is there any feature making this possible?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom control

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.10.0/examples/custom-controls.html

or even just some simple buttons to realize that.

You can calculcate the bounds and the center and take these coordinates to pan the map to the left,right,top,bottom.

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/hLzm22um/